# Windows Python2.7 path parsing error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm attempting to use the python 010 editor template [parser](http://d0cs4vage.blogspot.com/2015/08/pfp-python-interpreter-for-010-templates.html)

The doc specifically states (to get started):

```
import pfp
pfp.parse(data_file="C:\path2File\file.SWF",template_file="C:\path2File\SWFTemplate.bt")
```

However, it throws:

```
RuntimeError: Unable to invoke 'cpp'. Make sure its path was passed correctly
Original error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've tried everything, from using raw strings:

```
df = r"C:\path2File\file.swf"
tf = r"C:\path2File\SWFTemplate.bt"
```

To single and then double '\'s or '/'s in the string. However, it keeps throwing the above error message.

I checked the files are in the path and ensured everything is properly spelled, case sensitively.

To test my paths, I've used the windows "type" (equiv to *nix strings) and passed the strings as args in a subprocess.Popen which worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it's trying to invoke a C++ compiler: `cpp` and you don't have one.

You'll need to install one, or make sure that your `PATH` has a `cpp.exe` on it somewhere.

Comment: there aren't any compilers called cpp on windows (cl is the c++ compiler in MSVC). On *nix and ubuntu, there's only g++, searching on my ubuntu server didnt show any elf binary called 'cpp' and dpkg shows no candidates. google yielded no results regarding a 'cpp' binary either :(

Comment: Use the source, @grepNstepN! Open the `pfp` file(s) - you can find out where by adding `print pfp.__file__` to your source - and you should be able to find `cpp` in one of those files. I *believe* that `cpp` is the binary that VS produces... it's been quite a while since CS1, but I do remember using a cpp executable because I couldn't figure out what it was called on linux until I asked my brother ;)

Comment: thanks mate. I imported pfp and ran `print pfp.__file__` and it pointed to pfp's __init__.py which had cpp_path="cpp" and args as cpp_args="-xc++" several inports of its own. after checking on my coworker's linux box, he has it as a binary so I installed mingw on windows and have its path in my %PATH% environmental variable and its working (but throwing error messages, it wasnt specified on the site but it turns out pfp is meant for nix not windows)